# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable (REFPROP)

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, typeerror

I have a heat exchanger model where I am initializing the inputs and output array of some variables as:

```
[h_r_in1, t_ref1] = [[], []] #Input array
[h_r_in_o, t_ref_o] = [[], []] # overall refrigerant enthalpy and temperature array
```

Depending on the given input, I am calculating h_r_in1 and t_ref1 in different ways:

```
for jk, _ in enumerate(t_ref):
        for i, _ in enumerate(inputs_c['Circuits']):
            if quality_p > 0:
                # if refrigerant quality in input
                h_r_in1.append(
                refprop(inputs_c['Ref'][0], 'h', 'P', p_ref[jk][i], 'Q', t_ref[jk][i]))
                t_ref1.append(
                refprop(inputs_c['Ref'][0], 'T', 'P', p_ref[jk][i], 'Q', t_ref[jk][i]))
            else:
                # if refrigerant temperature in input
                h_r_in1.append(refprop(inputs_c['Ref'][0], 'h', 'T', t_ref[jk][i],
                                      'P', p_liq[jk][i])) 
                
        #        t_ref1.append(t_ref[jk][i]) 
                t_ref1.append(
                refprop(inputs_c['Ref'][0], 'T', 'P', p_ref[jk][i], 'h', h_r_in1[jk][i]))
        t_ref_o.append(t_ref1)
        h_r_in_o.append(h_r_in1)

        [h_r_in1, t_ref1] = [[], []]
```

Apparently, the problem seems to be when I calculate t_ref1 in the else statement, since I am using the calculated h_r_in1 and passing it to the call for calculating t_ref1. This gives me the error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "<ipython-input-10-389a56a8ed05>", line 1, in <module>
>     runfile('F:/Research work/Coil_Model/HeatExchanger_Model_Xfin/V_coil/Main_file_batch.py',
> wdir='F:/Research work/Coil_Model/HeatExchanger_Model_Xfin/V_coil')
> 
>   File
> "C:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
> line 705, in runfile
>     execfile(filename, namespace)
> 
>   File
> "C:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
> line 102, in execfile
>     exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
> 
>   File "F:/Research
> work/Coil_Model/HeatExchanger_Model_Xfin/V_coil/Main_file_batch.py",
> line 1470, in <module>
>     Sup, Mass = main_file(FILE_PATH, n_2, V_dot_air)
> 
>   File "F:/Research
> work/Coil_Model/HeatExchanger_Model_Xfin/V_coil/Main_file_batch.py",
> line 555, in main_file
>     refprop(inputs_c['Ref'][0], 'T', 'P', p_ref[jk][i], 'h', h_r_in1[jk][i]))
> 
> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post the full traceback. That's a lot easier than trying to figure out the errant line from the text.

Comment: Consider renaming your variables to something that make the more clear. I don't see any calculation other than appending to lists.

Comment: We don't know what `inputs_c`, `p_ref` etc... are. If you have a debugger you can check the values. Otherwise, just print them out on separate lines to make the error obvious. That is, `print(inputs_c['Ref'])`, `print(inputs_c['Ref'][0])` etc... Then you'll know where the unexpected float is.